# Extracting and formatting values as rows from an array within an array within an array

Tags: sql, arrays, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

The raw structure of the data looks as follows:

```
superarray:[
  array1:{
    subarray1:("id":"id1", "position":"1"),
    subarray2:("id":"id2", "position":"2"), 
    subarray3:("id":"id3", "position":"3"),
    subarray4:("id":"id4"), "position":"4")
  },  
  array2:{
    subarray5:("id":"id5", "position":"5"),
    subarray6:("id":"id6", "position":"6"), 
    subarray7:("id":"id7", "position":"7"),
    subarray8:("id":"id8", "position":"8") 
  },
  array3:{
    subarray9:("id":"id9, "position":"9")
  }
]
```

I can extract the outermost level of arrays using `FROM table, UNNEST(superarray) as super_array` to give the following:

```
+------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+
| Row_number | super_array.array | super_array.ids  | super_array.position |
+------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+
|          1 | array1            | id1              |                    1 |
|            |                   | id2              |                    2 |
|            |                   | id3              |                    3 |
|            |                   | id4              |                    4 |
|          2 | array2            | id5              |                    5 |
|            |                   | id6              |                    6 |
|            |                   | id7              |                    7 |
|            |                   | id8              |                    8 |
|          3 | array3            | id9              |                    9 |
+------------+-------------------+------------------+----------------------+
```

But I'm having trouble getting the inner level to give something like the following:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
| Row_number | array.array | array.ids  | array.position |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
|          1 | array1      | id1        |              1 |
|          2 | array1      | id2        |              2 |
|          3 | array1      | id3        |              3 |
|          4 | array1      | id4        |              4 |
|          5 | array2      | id5        |              5 |
|          6 | array2      | id6        |              6 |
|          7 | array2      | id7        |              7 |
|          8 | array2      | id8        |              8 |
|          9 | array3      | id9        |              9 |
+------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
```

How would I go about doing a second `UNNEST` without getting a duplicate column error? Do I need to `INSERT INTO` to add new rows for each individual id?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I don't know what to provide beyond the data structure outlined above, that's an accurate model with dummy variables. What else should I add to make the question more understandable?

Comment: ideally you should present CTE with sample data - `WITH sample_data AS (SELECT ...))`!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Ok I'll pull the question and repost with your suggestion

Comment: i would recommend not to pull out the question (maybe someone will be able to answer anyway ) but just update it when you have example data prepared

Comment: @AJG, if you still need assistance with this, could you provide sample data as Mikhail mentioned? Additionally, the expected output for that sample data and the query you have tried so far would be extra useful to try to figure this out.